# Webpack wont compile

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Hi I am trying to set up a react app with webpack. Currently when I try to run npm start I get the following error:

[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

- configuration.module.rules[0].use has an unknown property 'query'. These properties are valid:
  object { ident?, loader?, options? }

My webpack file is:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./entry.jsx",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react']
          }
        },
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", "*"]
  }
};
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Your configuration is invalid, the `query` prop is not supported. Did you mean to use `options` instead?

Comment: From https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#useentry "For compatibility a query property is also possible, which is an alias for the options property. Use the options property instead." Change query to `options`, I'm guessing `query` was deprecated at some point and has now been removed from the version you're using.

Comment: Options fixed it. Thanks a lot!